# Does "without" pronounce like "with 'out" or "wi 'thout"?

Tags: pronunciation

I don't know which version is correct.

"Without"'s phonetic symbol is `/wɪð'aʊt/`. Should I pronounce it like "with 'out" because the stree mark `'`is before `aʊ` instead before `ð`, or should I pronounce it like "wi thout" because I should pronounce it continuously?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? [*without*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/without) shows at least the two pronunciations you mention. So it probably depends on where you are, the speech pattern (formal, informal, etc.) and the context where used.

Answer (score 4):

The stress is on the second syllable. There is no pause.

Comment: Yes, that is what the issue is really here for the OP.

Comment: In relaxed speech I'd often just say **wiaʊt** (without any attempt to enunciate **ð** between the vowels, making it effectively a single-syllable tripthong). I'm Southern / Estuary English, but I'm pretty sure many Northerners / Scots do the same.

Comment: _Very_ relaxed, I'd say, verging on dialect. Often represented in writing as wi'out. Common in North East / "Geordie" speech.

Answer (score 0):

'out' is the part that is stressed. The dictionary's pronunciation is used for words in isolation. In rapid speech the pronunciation alters slightly. 'Out' begins with a vowel and English doesn't like to begin syllables with a vowel. The 'th' of 'with' will become the first sound of the stressed syllable in rapid speech. So, /wɪ 'ðaʊt/ is the pronunciation in rapid speech.